# Cloudfront distribution pointing to S3 bucket and ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb, http-status-code-502

I am trying to configure my cloudfront distribution to route requests for mydomain.com to an S3 bucket and requests for mydomain.com/api/* to an ELB.

In route 53, I have dev.mydomain.com pointing to the cloudfront distribution with an alias record

[Alias to cloudfront in route53](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l05MU.png)

I have configured two origins in cloudfront - one to S3 and one to a publicly accessible ELB

[Cloudfront origins setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHNZC.png)

I have configured one (on top of default) behavior to route api/* requests to the ELB origin

[Cloudfront behaviors setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CEui.png)

I have no issues with the S3 bucket. When I added the new behavior to route api/* requests to the ELB, I am receiving a 502 gateway error whenever I hit api/* routes.

When I make a request to the ELB from the origin I provided to Cloudfront, I am seeing the following response in Postman:

```
Error: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: 
Host: mydomain-api-dev-env.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.mydomain.com
```

This leads me to believe the 502 is because the ELB url is not included in mydomain.com's cert.

Assuming that this is my issue, how would I go about resolving this certificate issue since I don't own the elasticbeanstalk.com domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to **associate your own domain with the load balancer** and add proper SSL to it. Then in your CF distro, you are going to use your own ALB's domain, not the one provided by AWS.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without creating a subdomain specifically for the ALB? Do you have an example A record I could look at to see how this would be done in route53? Since dev.mydomain.com is already associated to the cloudfront distro, how would I associate the ALB to the domain?

Comment: @pantaphobic Yo can create second subdomain for the ALB, and get free SSL cert from AWS ACM for it.

Comment: I ended up creating an A record from dev-api.mydomain.com to the ELB. Then, in cloudfront I created a new origin pointing to dev-api.mydomain.com instead of the ELB so the certificate would be valid.